# How can I send a random message everyday from an array at a specific hour on discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that will send a random message from an array using cron.

Here is my code:

```
const cron = require('cron');

module.exports = {
    name: 'pesanrandom',
    description: "random message every day",
    execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){
      let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('00 54 16 * * *', () => {
        //
        var listPesan = [
          'Met siang guys, dah pada mam siang blum?',
          'Siapa yang tadi pagi mimpiin cowo atau cewe kpopnya',
          'Siang-siang enaknya...',
          'Dor kaget ga',
          'Laper dah',
        ];

        var pesanRandom = listPesan[Math.floor(Math.random() * listPesan.length)];

        const pesanEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('#50C878')
              .setTitle('vermillion#3039')
              .setDescription(pesanRandom)
              .setFooter('© Vermillion')

        client.channels.cache.get('927589065925214239').send(pesanEmbed);
        //
      });

      scheduledMessage.start()
    }
}
```

I already try the code and it works but it can only randomize the message one time. How to make it randomize the message everytime the message is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easiest way to do this requires two files. One file we are going to call `listPesan.json` and in that file we will have this text:

```json
[
    "Met siang guys, dah pada mam siang blum?",
    "Siapa yang tadi pagi mimpiin cowo atau cewe kpopnya",
    "Siang-siang enaknya...",
    "Dor kaget ga",
    "Laper dah"
]
```

The second file is your main.js bot file and somewhere (doesn't matter where so long as it is not under an event (.on('messageCreate'), .on('guildMemberAdd'), etc.)

This stands alone all by itself (you can put your `const` stuff together if you want) and we are going to use `node-cron`, it's "better" supposedly, idk, I've just always used it.

```js
const cron = require('node-cron')
const listPesan = require('./listPesan.json') // or where ever you put the file we just made above

cron.schedule('00 54 16 * * *', () => {

const pesanRandom = listPesan[Math.floor(Math.random() * listPesan.length)]

const pesanEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#50c878')
    .setTitle('vermillion#3039')
    .setDescription(pesanRandom)
    .setFooter('© Vermillion')
    
    
    // if using discord v12
    client.channels.cache.get('927589065925214239').send(pesanEmbed)
    
    // if using discord v13
    client.channels.cache.get('927589065925214239').send({
        embeds: [pesanEmbed]
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem. I think the problem here is because I'm using cron and now I agree that node-cron is better than cron XD. I hope you have a great day~!

Comment: So the issue was that you were triggering it via a command called `pesanrandom` which when triggered would start a cron process, however if the bot was ever rebooted or restarted that cron process would end and you would have to send the command again. By adding it to the main.js file, you eliminate the need for a command and it will just run "on time" so long as the bot is online when that time comes around.

Comment: I see, so I'll move it to my main.js rather than trigger it manually using commands.

Comment: Correct and it will run automatically from then on.